# Giving WixUIExtension dialogs a slightly more modern look

Tags: wix

I feel that the dialogs provided by the WixUIExtension have a look that remembers me of Windows 95.

Example screenshot from an [example of the WiX Tutorial](https://www.firegiant.com/wix/tutorial/user-interface/first-steps/) built with WiX 3.10 (*cough* on Win 7):

[image: Sample Screenshot]

(I know how to replace the bitmaps.) The icons (disks, folders) have 16 colors, text boxes and combo boxes look quite old.

Maybe I missed something obvious.

Is there a way to give these dialogs a slightly more modern look without rewriting them from scratch?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can replace the bitmaps and icons but the controls and their appearance are part of MSI and can't be changed. That's one of the reasons I use Burn bundles even when I don't have a chain -- it requires coding but the UI can be completely controlled.